# Oracle Global Temp Table in Packages

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

If I have a package that is using a GTT (global temp table) will the procedures or functions within the package be able to access data from the same session? 
Example:
If I insert data into the table via a routine in Procedure#1 can Procedure#2 access the data from this GTT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  It is only scoped to that session/connection though.  See a [tutorial](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables.php)